# ADFS: Show active sessions and logout users from server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, adfs

To develop and test a single sign-on ADFS solution, we have set up a Windows 2012 server with ADFS. The single sign-on process now works, and it possible for our service (acting as a *Service Provider*) to authenticate with this ADFS-server (acting as the *Identity Provider*).

To develop the single log-out functionality, I would like to be able to logout users as an administrator from a remote desktop session with this Windows server, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Is there a tool that lists all active user sessions, including those who authenticated via ADFS?

If a user authenticates with our service successfully, the `qwinsta` tool doesn't show any sessions for that user. Can that tool be used, or is a user authenticated via ADFS a different beast and should I use a different tool?

And once I know the session-ID of the authenticated user, how do I terminate their ADFS session?